# sql order by variable with different data type

Tags: sql

I have following query

```
DECLARE @OrderBy INT
SET @OrderBy = 1
DECLARE @PageSize INT
SET @PageSize = 10
DECLARE @PageIndex INT
SET @PageIndex = 1


SELECT exp.ExportId
    ,exp.ExportDate
    ,exp.UniqueExportId
    ,exp.ExporterOfRecord
    ,exp.PartNo
    ,exp.Description
    ,exp.AvailQty AS Quantity
    ,exp.UnitOfMeasuremnt
    ,exp.Destination
    --,exp.ScheduledB,
    ,tp.HTSUS AS ScheduledB
FROM tblCASIDD_Export exp
    LEFT JOIN tblCASIDD_Part tp
    ON tp.PartNo = exp.PartNo


ORDER BY (
        CASE @OrderBy
            WHEN 1
                THEN exp.PartNo
            WHEN 2
                THEN exp.ExportDate
            END
        ) OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1) ROWS

FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

when i give orderby 1 (varchar) it throws error

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Its throwing error with data type other than date type

while with date type its working

any suggestion what i am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of all options in the `ORDER BY` CASE statement need to match, so you'll need to cast to something common e.g.

```
CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 1
            THEN CAST(exp.PartNo AS NVARCHAR(20))
        WHEN 2
            THEN CAST(exp.ExportDate AS NVARCHAR(20))
        END
```

(The optimal type to cast to will depend on the native types of `PartNo` and `ExportDate`)

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d36b/2)

Comment: With cast i have done, but why its throwing error in different datat type

Comment: Can you please give the exact types of `PartNo` and `ExportDate` ?

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam - because `CASE` expressions are a general form of expression - it's an *unusual* case here that all rows will return values from the *same* `THEN` clause. As such, the code has to be generated to expect a mix of values from any of the `THEN` clauses (or the `ELSE` clause). And so SQL has to decide what the data type is for the entire `CASE` expression - it takes all of the possible data types from each clause, and then uses the precedence rules to determine a single data type that all the clauses values will be converted to. In your case, it picked `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

As Stuart says, all possible values of a `CASE` expression must be convertible to a single type. Stuart's shown [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090293/15498) to fix this but that tends to ruin the "expected" sort order when mixing data types. It usually better to do it as two (or more) separate `CASE` expressions<sup>1</sup> that can then have their natural types (and the other `CASE` expressions evaluate to `NULL`s which all sort together)

```
ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy WHEN 1 THEN exp.PartNo END,
         CASE @OrderBy WHEN 2 THEN exp.ExportDate END
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1) ROWS
```

<sup>1</sup>You'd normally have one `CASE` expression for each desired final data type. So if you have 3 possible `int` columns to sort on, and 2 `datetime` columns, you'd still just have 2 `CASE` expressions - one dealing with all of the `int` columns, and the other dealing with the `datetime` columns.